# Solve the limit $\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{4}}{x-3}$ with no l'Hopital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Solve the limit without using de l'Hopital rule: $$\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{4}}{x-3}$$

It looks like classical example of squeeze theorem, but I completely can't develop the intuition how to estimate lower and upper bounds. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit (solution):**
According to hint of user @Omnomnomnom, we notice that the limit is derivative.
$$x=h+3$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{4+h}-\sqrt[3]{4}}{h}$$

It is derivative of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ in the point $x=4$. Thus:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$
Substituting the point $x=4$
$$\frac{1}{3\cdot4^{\frac{2}{3}}} = \frac{1}{3\cdot2^{\frac{4}{3}}} = \frac{1}{6\sqrt[3]{2}}$$

Comment: Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator by $(x+1)^{2/3}+4^{1/3}(x+1)^{1/3}+4^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** This limit is simply the derivative of *something*.  Can you figure it out from there?

(If it helps, make the substitution $x = 3+h$ so that we have a limit as $h \to 0$).

Comment: I get $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{4+h}-\sqrt[3]{4}}{h}$. It resembles the definition of derivative, but there is no variable.

Comment: It's the derivative of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ **at** $x = 4$.

Comment: Thanks. I added my solution to my post according to your hints.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The fraction is of the form
$$\frac{a-b}{a^3-b^3}$$
so you can factor the denominator and cancel the factor that goes to zero.

Can you find the appropriate choices for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $\frac{(x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-2^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(x+1)^{1}-2^{\frac{6}{3}}}$. That's nice, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the propertie:
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2). $$

Indeed:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{4}}{x-3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{4}}{x-3}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{x+1}\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{4^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{x+1}\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{4^2}}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}\frac{(\sqrt[3]{x+1})^3-(\sqrt[3]{4})^2}{(x-3)(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{x+1}\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{4^2})} =$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{x+1}\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{4^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4^2}+\sqrt[3]{4}\cdot\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{4^2}} =\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{16}}.$$

Comment: Good! It is according to the result given after applying L'Hospital rule!

Answer (score 0):

Let us put $y = x + 1$ so that $y \to 4$ and then we have $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{x \to 3}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x + 1} - \sqrt[3]{4}}{x - 3}\\
&= \lim_{y \to 4}\frac{y^{1/3} - 4^{1/3}}{y - 4}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\cdot 4^{(1/3) - 1} = \frac{1}{3\cdot 4^{2/3}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{16}}\end{aligned}$$ We have used the formula $$\lim_{y \to a}\frac{y^{n} - a^{n}}{y - a} = na^{n - 1}$$